# Which electron is knocked off a Helium atom?

Tags: spin

When a He atom is ionized, which electron is removed first, the one with the spin up or down? or is it just random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting question! Does the **polarization** of ionizing radiation interact with electron spin? [Apparently, that has been investigated to some extent](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/16/10/103028), and some [spin information can be obtained from an entangled electron and photon](http://jablab2.case.edu/singlephotons.htm).

So the answer to your question is not a clear-cut "yes" or "no", but depends on the parameters of the incident photon.

Comment: Very interesting, but this seems to be overthinking the question. Without additional constraints on how the ionization is achieved I believe that the answer is that it is just random.

Comment: @MaxW, agreed... without the (bolded) polarization, it's not meaningful, but with that constraint, a user might learn from it.

Comment: Hm, without an external field that gives orientation, the answer should be "can't tell", shouldn't it? Because if a single He atom is all the reference available, the photon doesn't even have a distinct polarisation.